# Livereload not reloading browser

Tags: guard, livereload

I'm using `guard` and `live-reload` with Drupal locally.

When I load run `bundle exec guard`, guard monitors my files properly so that when I save changes to a sass file it automatically recompiles.

The only thing that doesn't refresh is the browser. livereload.js is loaded in the page but it doesn't seem to auto-refresh. I am using Ubuntu with both Chromium and Firefox, and neither work I'm struggling to troubleshoot as I don't get an error messages.

Here is the output when I run `bundle exec guard`

```
13:48:51 - INFO - Guard::Compass is waiting to compile your stylesheets.
13:48:51 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
13:48:51 - INFO - Guard::Compass is waiting to compile your stylesheets.
13:48:51 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/var/www/websites/sites/all/themes/first_omega_subtheme'
```

when I change a sass file this happens

```
unchanged sass/reset.scss
unchanged sass/hacks.scss
overwrite css/styles.css
unchanged sass/reset.scss
unchanged sass/hacks.scss
unchanged sass/styles.scss
13:36:50 - INFO - Reloading browser: css/styles.css
```

and when I refresh my browser this happens

```
15:12:13 - INFO - Browser disconnected.
15:12:13 - INFO - Browser connected.
```

and the page shows the changes I just can't get it to auto refresh

Comment: I managed to get this working, my problem was that I was using subdomains so all my sites were suffixed with .localhost and in the settings I had not put the specific site. I just needed to add foo.localhost and bar.localhost. Can't believe I didn't spot this.

Comment: Where did you add the `.localhost` ??

Comment: in the settings of the theme, I think it needs the host of whatever the site is served as mine were all local so that's why I used localhost

Comment: Interesting... I'm also working with a local environment, but I can't find any gem or guard file references to a localhost setting. Do you remember what file you updated by chance?

Comment: you add it in the theme settings in the UI of drupal

Comment: Aha... I missed the "Drupal" part. Yikes - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to install a browser extension

```
 https://github.com/downloads/siasia/livereload-extensions/LiveReload-2.0.9.xpi
```

and after installation try to restart all browser and connect it again it will work otherwise read monre on

```
 https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload/issues/88
```